# jenkins ec2-plugin permission issue for users

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

we launch ec2 Jenkins slave using ec2-plugin. Default user is ec2-user. In log i see it again try to connect root. so basically Jenkins home directory "/var/jenkins_home" or "/home/ec2-user" or any other steps performed by root owned by root. so we need to do chown to ec2-user in my pipeline job stages. I have tried to set jenkins home dir to /home/ec2-user, but still same issue since root download files or run scripts. Then I have tried to chown all these for ec2-user in init script (end of script) but still same issue. I had set root and slave command prefix both to sudo in ec2-plugin configuration. Can we get rid of this permission issue?

Comment: I don't understand everything that you write, but you can configure the EC2 plugin to log in as `ec2-user` in its configuration.

Comment: We have ec2-user in plugin config, but Jenkins job which we run on this ec2 slave facing permission issue, so we need to chown of lots of folders. I tried to explain workarounds which i have tried

Answer (score 0):

I cant get rid of chown because I was running jenkins as a container and mounting the Host volume in it.